Elegant way to validate multiple properties are non-null and report errors?
Given that I have an API model where all fields are nullable and a corresponding domain model where all fields are required:
data class MyApiModel(
    val property1: Int?,
    val property2: String?,
    val property3: Boolean?,
)

data class MyDomainModel(
    val property1: Int,
    val property2: String,
    val property3: Boolean,
)

I want to write a mapping function that will convert an instance of the API model to the domain model, validating that all of the field are non-null. I want the function to return this ModelMapperResult containing a list of the validation errors:
data class ModelMapperResult<T>(
    val value: T,
    val validationErrors: List<String>,
)

I'm trying to find a coding pattern to do this that satisfies two goals:

It should be reasonably ergonomic; the code should be relatively easy to read and write.
It should be safe e.g. prefer smart casts and constructs like let over the double bang (!!) operator.

As of now, I haven't figured out a good way to do this and so I'm using mapping code that only returns the first validation error it encounters:
fun MyApiModel.toDomainModel(): ModelMapperResult<MyDomainModel?> {
    val property1 = property1 ?: return ModelMapperResult(null, listOf("Missing property1"))
    val property2 = property2 ?: return ModelMapperResult(null, listOf("Missing property2"))
    val property3 = property3 ?: return ModelMapperResult(null, listOf("Missing property3"))

    return ModelMapperResult(
        value = MyDomainModel(
            property1 = property1,
            property2 = property2,
            property3 = property3,
        ),
        validationErrors = emptyList(),
    )
}

Any ideas?

Your usage pattern suggests you might be better off using something like Arrow's Either class instead of a class that has two properties, only one of which is valid at any time.

This is the classic problem with Kotlin where the domain model has mandatory fields, yet you want to allow "loose" input via a REST interface such that you can report multiple errors to the caller - and in particular allowing the caller to make mistakes by omitting several fields, but you want to inform the caller that they must provide values for those fields.
The only solution we came up with, like you, is to have two different objects.  On the outer / API model there are no mandatory fields (and other "loose" field types that I will explain later), then your inner domain model that is properly typed with fields properly mandated.
I think you want a tool to validate and gather multiple errors and secondly to pass the data into the domain model.
We have solved the first part, but not the second.  For validation we have used a library called Konform:

allows you to write an elegant syntax to describe common validation (e.g. required fields)
checks for common validation rules, like number range checks, string lengths
ability to check a String really is a Date, or Time, or Enum value (that's what I mean about loose field input)
ability to extend to write your own validators
employ some switching logic in the validator
collect errors in a collection in a pair of field name and condition that the field is breaking.  From this you can produce a rich object back to your caller with the errors

import io.konform.validation.Constraint
import io.konform.validation.Invalid
import io.konform.validation.Validation
import io.konform.validation.ValidationBuilder
import io.konform.validation.ValidationResult
import io.konform.validation.jsonschema.enum
import io.konform.validation.jsonschema.maxLength
import io.konform.validation.jsonschema.minLength
import io.konform.validation.jsonschema.minimum
import java.math.RoundingMode
import java.time.LocalDate

class MyApiModel(
    val property1: Int?,
    val requiredProperty2a: String?,
    val optionalProperty2b: String?,
    val property3: Boolean?,
    val enumProperty4: String?,
    val dateProperty5: String?,
) : Validatable<MyApiModel> {
    override fun validate() = Validation {
        MyApiModel::property1 required { minimum(0) }
        MyApiModel::requiredProperty2a required { 
            minLength(2)
            maxLength(100)
        }
        MyApiModel::optionalProperty2b ifPresent { minLength(8) }
        MyApiModel::enumProperty4 required { enum<RoundingMode>() }
        MyApiModel::dateProperty5 required { validateLocalDate() }
    }(this)
}

// a customised validator for LocalDate
fun ValidationBuilder<String>.validateLocalDate(): Constraint<String> {
    return addConstraint("Supply an ISO8601 date in format: yyyy-MM-dd") {
        try {
            LocalDate.parse(it)
            true
        } catch (e: RuntimeException) {
            false
        }
    }
}

// a general interfaces (not really needed)
interface Validatable<T> {
    fun validate(): ValidationResult<T>
    fun assertValid() {
        validate().let { validationResult ->
            if (validationResult is Invalid<T>) {
                // a simple way to list out the errors...
                throw RuntimeException(listOf(validationResult).flatMap { it.errors }.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}

The second challenge is how to map to the Domain Object.  We do this in two different places, depending on how much the API model is used.  Either we have a function inside the API object that transforms it to the Domain model, or we do inside the Service class.  But either way we can guarantee that the Konform validation has executed so !! calls are safe, as are parsing of dates, enum values, etc.
Since we're also using Spring and we wrote a small adaption to invoke the validation automatically before the controller method is called.  It works well overall and we have this employed on hundreds of end points.
(Konform documentation is a bit obscure - look at the Unit Tests, this is the best way to discover the DSL)

You can use contracts:
data class ModelMapperResult<T>(
    val value: T,
    val validationErrors: List<String>,
)

@OptIn(ExperimentalContracts::class)
fun notNull(value: Any?, ifNull: () -> Unit): Boolean {
    contract { returns(true) implies (value != null) }
    if (value == null)
        ifNull()
    return value != null
}

fun MyApiModel.toDomainModel(): ModelMapperResult<MyDomainModel?> =
    with(mutableListOf<String>()) {
    if (notNull(property1) { add("property1 is missing") }
        && notNull(property2) { add("property2 is missing") }
        && notNull(property3) { add("property3 is missing") })
            ModelMapperResult(MyDomainModel(property1, property2, property3), emptyList())
        else
            ModelMapperResult(null, this)
}

However, your definition of ModelMapperResult is sub-optimal: it has two properties, only one of which is valid at any one point. You can instead take inspiration from Arrow's Either class and create a sealed class that has one of two possible alternatives: a success or a failure, each one holding only one property.
sealed class ModelMapperResult<T> {
    data class Success<T>(val value: T): ModelMapperResult<T>()
    data class Failure<T>(val validationErrors: List<String>): ModelMapperResult<T>()
}

Your original ModelMapperResult can be easily abused: your users might assume that the result was a success and try to use the value property without checking. An advantage of this sealed class is that it forces your users to check if they have a success or failure, so it can't be abused this way. With this definition, the mapper can be like this:
fun MyApiModel.toDomainModel(): ModelMapperResult<MyDomainModel> =
    with(mutableListOf<String>()) {
        if (notNull(property1) { add("property1 is missing") }
            && notNull(property2) { add("property2 is missing") }
            && notNull(property3) { add("property3 is missing") })
            ModelMapperResult.Success(MyDomainModel(property1, property2, property3))
        else
            ModelMapperResult.Failure(this)
    }

And it has to be used in a type-safe way, like this:
    val result = apiModel.toDomainModel()
    when (result) {
        is ModelMapperResult.Success -> println(result.value)
        is ModelMapperResult.Failure -> println(result.validationErrors)
    }


Thank you for pointing me toward contracts! That seems to be the exact missing piece I'm looking for. FWIW I'm not using Either because certain validation errors might be recoverable and I want to enable the use case of successfully returning a result even if there are validation errors.

Unfortunately, I just realized this code doesn't work because the && operator will short circuit the evaluation when it encounters its first false expression, which means only the first missing property error will be reported. And switching to and to avoid short-circuiting doesn't work because it doesn't appear to play nicely with smart-casting.
